# Is there a phrasal verb that means come in a timely manner?

Tags: phrase-request, phrasal-verbs

I thought it was "came about", but after a quick Google search it doesn't seem to be used like that. I think the verb come is used, but I am not sure what's exactly the phrasal verb that has a meaning close to or the same meaning that I am looking for.

Comment: Could you please add an example sentence where you would use this phrase?

Comment: Do you mean [**come along**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/come-along)?  It's hard to tell what you're asking for without some context.

Comment: The best one I can think of is the second instance of the archaic verb in [*Cometh the hour, **cometh** the man*](https://idiomorigins.org/origin/cometh-the-hour-cometh-the-man#:~:text=Origin%20of%3A%20Cometh%20the%20hour%2C%20cometh%20the%20man&text=It%20means%20that%20no%20matter,tide%20and%20win%20the%20contest.) ("the man" arrives in a "timely" manner, ***exactly and only when he is needed***). I can't think of a "modern" equivalent with exactly that sense.

Comment: ...But it's not clear exactly what OP means by "arrive in a timely manner". If *someone who is being talked about* unexpectedly turns up, you might say his arrival was "timely" (being highly relevant to the current topic of conversation). In *that* context, we might use the "set phrase" ***Talk of the Devil**!* (and here he is!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are loads of phrasal verbs that mean to hurry something along, perhaps to *ensure* that something happens on time, such as "*chase up*", "*hurry along*", or "*chivvy along*" (NB the latter is chiefly British) but I can't think of one that specifically means "to arrive in a timely fashion".

Thing is, a phrasal verb is used like a verb, and can only really mean one action. For example, "turn up" means to arrive, but not necessarily *on-time*. You need to also use an *adverb* to include the *manner* in which the verb action is carried out. You could simply say "arrive punctually". If you really must use a phrasal verb, you could use "turn up" or something synonymous, and add an adverb like "punctually", or "on time".